# How to figure the missing values by comparing between two data frames

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I just want to figure the missing values between two data frames so....
Here's the code I tried and works fine

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], columns=["my_column"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=["my_column"])

result = df1[~df1.set_index(list(df1)).index.isin(df2.set_index(list(df2)).index)].dropna()


print(result)
```

Output:

```
   my_column
3          4
4          5
5          6
```

So it works fine on a static dataframe....

But I figure a problem when I use this code based on sql:
So here's my full code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, Date, Float
import datetime as dt

# connect db
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://xxxxxxxxxx\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
connection = engine.connect()


esn_datafeed_query = 'SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[esn_datafeed]'
esn_inter_intra_query = 'SELECT * FROM [esn_inter_intra_merge]'

esn_datafeed_df = pd.read_sql(esn_datafeed_query ,engine)
esn_inter_intra_merge_df = (esn_inter_intra_query, engine)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(esn_datafeed_df, columns=["st_umts_df_relation_key"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(esn_inter_intra_merge_df, columns=["st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key"])

result = df1[~df1.set_index(list(df1)).index.isin(df2.set_index(list(df2)).index)].dropna()


print(result)
```

So the previous code Is shows all the values, I don't need this... I just want to show missing values only.... I tried it with different way as the below code:

```
esn_datafeed_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[esn_datafeed]', engine)
esn_inter_intra_merge_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[esn_inter_intra_merge]', engine)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(esn_datafeed_df, columns=["st_umts_df_relation_key"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(esn_inter_intra_merge_df, columns=["st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key"])

merged = df1.merge(df2 , how="left", indicator=True)
result = merged.query("_merge == 'left_only'")[["st_umts_df_relation_key"]]

print(result)
```

but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/tool_check_nbr/my_missing_result.py", line 18, in <module>
    merged = df1.merge(df2 , how="left", indicator=True)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7336, in merge
    return merge(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 68, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 619, in __init__
    self._validate_specification()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1183, in _validate_specification
    raise MergeError(
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False
```

## Edited

I tried also this code:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
```

but I find this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/tool_check_nbr/my_missing_result.py", line 23, in <module>
    df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7336, in merge
    return merge(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 68, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 619, in __init__
    self._validate_specification()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1183, in _validate_specification
    raise MergeError(
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False
```

So to explain in brief related to my database I have two tables

`esn_datafeed`
[image: esn_datafeed]

and this is the second table `esn_inter_intra_merge`

[image: st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key]

So now I want to figure the difference between the two tables which I need to figure the values in `esn_datafeed.st_umts_df_relation_key` which is not in `esn_inter_intra_merge.st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key`

So anyone have any idea how to solve this.....
May be due to the large data in the database?

Is there's a way to do with a query so it will be okay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your new dataframes use different names for the columns.  However, it sounds like you should be using sets anyway.  Here is how to get the [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) between values between two columns.

```
missing_values = set(df1.iloc[:, 0]).symmetric_difference(set(df2.iloc[:, 0]))
>>> missing_values
{4, 5, 6}
```

Then you can check if the dataframe values are in these missing values.

```
>>> df1[df1.iloc[:, 0].isin(missing_values)]
   my_column
3          4
4          5
5          6
```

**EDIT**

Upon further reflection, isn't this simply a SQL question that has nothing to do with pandas?

Does something like this work?  This SQL query selects all records from `t1` (`esn_datafeed`) where there are no corresponding values of `st_umts_df_relation_key` in the `st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key` column of `t2` (`esn_inter_intra_merge`).

```
SELECT * 
FROM esn_datafeed AS t1
LEFT JOIN esn_inter_intra_merge AS t2
ON t1.st_umts_df_relation_key = t2.st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key
WHERE t2.st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for your support it give me the same out shows all values not the missing values

Comment: Perhaps you should add your expected result to your question to help clarify.  I edited my answer, but I'm not sure if it is what you want.

Comment: it's hard to show the expected result because I have millions of rows, but let me edit my question I'll  try to discuss more

Comment: should I have to make a relation between two tables in sql?...
that's may be gives me the wrong out?

Comment: thanks alot it works with the query but I don't know why it doesn't work correctly with pandas